# Как вывести ошибку в программу?

Tags: python, файлы, обработка-ошибок

У меня есть программа, которая должна открыть файл введенный пользователем:

```
name = input("введите название файла: ")
f = open(name, 'r')
```

Если  не найден файл, указанный пользователем, он выводит ошибку в консоль разработчика:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.png'
```

Возможно ли при такой ошибке выводить прямо пользователю в программу какой то текст, например "такого файла не существует" или что-то в этом духе?

Я представляю себе это так:

```
name = input("введите название файла: ")
f = open(name, 'r')
if error:
    print("error")
```

Код выше не правильный. Я просто могу предполагать, что он может выглядеть приблизительно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь обработкой ошибок - `try: ... except ...`

```
while True:
    try:
        name = input("введите название файла: ")
        with open(name, 'r') as f: 
            # здесь используем переменную `f`
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("error")
```